# CLion powers off my computer

Tags: crash, clion

*Sometimes*, when I start CLion, my computer *instantaneously* powers off. I have tried running `clion` and writing all output (stdout and stderr) to a file and after a crash it only contains this:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I have the following configuration

- CLion 1.2.4  Build #CL-143.1186.2
- JDK: 1.8.0_51
- VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
- Vendor: Oracle Corporation
- OS: Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

I have crashed 3 out of 3 times today. 2 times when I start CLion, the last time was when it was indexing my project (i.e. it started up).

What am I doing wrong and more important: How can this be fixed?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: As for actually helping you: the only thing I can think of is clion is causing your machine to overheat and trigger the thermal shutdown.

Comment: My computer is cold as a breeze... But next time it happens, I will try to look at `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/debug`

Comment: I'd hazard an arbitrary guess that it's the fault of your JVM rather than CLion. Alternatively it could be thermal shutdown, but that's easy to check and besides, CLion is not _that_ power-hungry.

Comment: I am pretty certain that it is not thermal shutdown. Although since this post, nothing improper have happened